# How can I reach nested in nested dictionary values?

Tags: python, arrays, json, nested

```
{
'data':[
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "hobbies": ["running", "sky diving", "singing"],
    "age": 35,
    "children": [
        {
            "firstName": "Sandy,
            "age": 6
            "values":[
                       {
                      'value' :908
                        } 
                      ]
        },
        {        
            "firstName": "Alice",
            "age": 7
            "values":[
                       {
                      'value' :0123
                        } 
                      ]
        }
        {        
            "firstName": "Dany",
            "age": 8
            "values":[
                       {
                      'value' :0193
                        } 
                      ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is my json file .I try to reach first names ,values and age each block and write database.**I tried  a lot of things and I cant run ..

> ```
> .
> .
> results=r.json()
>
> for k in results['data']:
>   for k1 in k['children']:
>    data={"firstname":k1['firstName']....?Values?)
> ```

How can I reach each block values and every values in one json format ?

Comment: That is not a valid json

Comment: What did you mean ?

Comment: The brackets at the "firstname"/"lastname" level should be `{}` not `[]`.

Comment: Okey .Is there any way reach this data ? Json or another ı have to reach each data and ı want to write in one json format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your example is coming from the web. But as Alberto Poljak and fizzybear pointed your json format was somewhat broken.

I corrected it here and there [image: corrections - screenshot] and in this format it should work:

```
{
"data":
{
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "hobbies": ["running", "sky diving", "singing"],
    "age": 35,
    "children": [
        {
            "firstName": "Sandy",
            "age": 6,
            "values":[
                       {
                      "value" :908
                        } 
                      ]
        },
        {        
            "firstName": "Alice",
            "age": 7,
            "values":[
                       {
                      "value" :123
                        } 
                      ]
        },
        {        
            "firstName": "Dany",
            "age": 8,
            "values":[
                       {
                      "value" :193
                        } 
                      ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you save the above in a file "family.json" then this sample code should be working fine:

```
import json

with open('family.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    p = data['data']['children']
    for r in p:
        print('First name: %s' % r['firstName'])
        print('Age: %d' % r['age'])            
        print('')
```

For quick review of json files you can use e.g. https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer, where you can validate it or see its content in a tree structure etc..